# FolderPicker does not work in UWP Windows 10 app (mobile)

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, win-universal-app, uwp, windows-10-mobile

I am developing an UWP Windows 10 app.
Given following code sample....

```
using Windows.Storage;
using Windows.Storage.Pickers;

FolderPicker picker = new FolderPicker() { SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary };

picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg");
StorageFolder folder = await picker.PickSingleFolderAsync();

if (folder != null) { ... work ... }
```

...**everything works fine on Desktop**.

**On Mobile, unfortunately** (build 10.0.10549), the first time I invoke the method, a system-dialog appears where I can choose "My device" as a single option. Clicking this option results in a start of the system-file-explorer-app followed by an immediate close/crash/whatever of that app.
So I find myself back in my own app with `folder == null`. When I now try to run the given snippet again, `PickSingleFolderAsync()` throws an UnauthorizedAccessException ("Access is denied"). However, if I place a breakpoint on the line with `PickSingleFolderAsync()`, the app does not crash but like in the first try, the file-explorer app returns immediately again, without any folder.

Reference zu method: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.pickers.folderpicker.picksinglefolderasync

Comment: Strange thing - the first time I've tested your code, I got null, but now I cannot reproduce it - every time it works. Can you check your capabilitied and in declarations there is 'File Open Picker'. Though, now I have unchecked all capabilities and declarations and it still works.

Comment: Most probably I have a buggy build or broken file explorer app, will test it on my other devices as soon as the "deploy-bug" on the latest build is fixed

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the Win10 mobile build 10572 fix the error. I have experienced the same folderpicker issue with build 10549, but after updating to 10572, it works.

Added 05/Nov/2015 - App deployment from VS to Win10M devices works well with VS2015 Update1 RC + Win10M 10581. You may see the error messagebox when you tried to 'Run without debug', but deploy itself works.

Comment: are you able to deploy on your 10572-phone? For many, this is currently not possible: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/10409958-b53b-43f8-8942-6040f6256b56

Comment: Yes. VS have an issue but other way works well. 1) using deviceportal or 2) using WinAppDeployCmd.   Following my blog posts are in Japanese, but the screencapture may helps you ... I hope so :)  http://ddlgjp.blogspot.jp/2015/10/deviceportal-uwp-app-win10-mobile.html

Comment: Didnt know of the Deviceportal since now. Isnt very comfortable as I always have to build apppackages to test the app and I cannot debug - but better than nothing!